# Redirect to concreate activity with notifications

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm using Notifications in Android. When the user clicks them, I have to open the application and redirect him to one specific Activity, it works fine if the user who gets the notifications didn't have the application opened. (I mean, opened in background), if he has the application opened, when he clicks the notification he is redirected to the "Main" activity when I want to redirect him to the same activity.

I guess that it could be some mistake in my AndroidManifest.xml,, but, I'm not sure, could you someone help me??

My manifest:

```
       <application
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <!-- android:theme="@style/AppTheme"  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"  -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.trivialword.activities.MainDisplayActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.trivialword.activities.ResultActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_result" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
```

And here is where I configure the notification

```
Context contexto = context.getApplicationContext();
CharSequence title = "Trivial Invitación";
CharSequence description = "Invitacion a una partida del usuario " + msg;

Intent notIntent = new Intent(contexto,
    GameOnePlayerPrivateOnlineActivity.class);

notIntent.putExtra("opponent", true);
notIntent.putExtra("who-create-game", msg);

PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    contexto, 0, notIntent, 0);

notif.setLatestEventInfo(
    contexto, title, description, contIntent);
```

Thank you!.

Comment: I am fetching same issue. Have you solve this issue ? If YES, then please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In intent declaration, try to write this.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

> Creating a simple notification:
>
> // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
>   `Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);`

I think, that is the problem.